# How to look for substring in string where substring is IN a seperate table on Access Query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

First, here is my code:

```
SELECT SSIInspectors.Inspector, SSIInspectors.Date_Time_of_Inspection
FROM SSIInspectors
WHERE (((SSIInspectors.Inspector) In (select [ProjectManager].[Lastname Firstname] from [ProjectManager])));
```

Essentially, I am trying to find the substring "Lastname FirstName" from the ProjectManager table inside the SSIINspector.Inspector field.

For example, in the [Lastname First Name] field of Project Manager table I have the following names

```
Smith, Jane
Kenny, Mike
```

and then in the SSIInspector.Inspector field I have:

```
"Doe, JohnSmith, JaneBob, Billy"
```

I want to be able to pick up "Smith, Jane" in my query. I tried using the "Like" function, but not quite sure how to use it in my particular query, or if I should be using wild cards?

Comment: Is this an actual multi-valued field, or is this a column where some code has just been concatenating strings? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-multivalued-fields-7c2fd644-3771-48e4-b6dc-6de9bebbec31

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.[Lastname Firstname]
FROM [ProjectManager] t1
INNER JOIN [SSIInspectors] t2
    ON t2.[Inspector] LIKE '*' & t1.[Lastname Firstname] & '*'
```

However, your data appears to not be normalized at all.  It would be much better to have all names on separate rows, and to have separate columns for the first and last names.